# How to change the height of the navigation bar in the Gumby CSS framework?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, css-frameworks

I am using the [Gumby CSS framework](http://gumbyframework.com). I am simply trying to change the height of the navigation bar from the default of 60px to 40px. In the _settings.scss file I have changed "$navcontain-height" to 40px but this has no effect at all, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
max-height: 40px;
```

i hope this will work

**EDIT** do not forget to update

```
min-height: 60px;
```

to

```
 min-height: 40px;
```

OR you can just update min-height to 40px and then set height it will also work

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions do change the height of the bar but not completely. The links are no longer vertically centered and the `li` elements still have a height of 60px. Also, I still don't know what "$navcontain-height" does. (I tried, for example, `.navbar {height: 42px;min-height: 42px;max-height: 42px;}`

Comment: `$navcontain-height` is sass way of declaring height, i think they will be using this height on multiple places

Comment: there is also height decleared in `.navbar ul li` you can set that accordingly

Comment: That's why I thought that changing it in the settings file would alter the height automatically. Thanks again.

Comment: Setting `height` in `.navbar ul li` still leaves the vertical align incorrect. I could then set `.navbar ul li > a` to have `line-height: 42px;` but I feel that `$navcontain-height` should do something and changing the height shouldn't require so much extra CSS given how Gumby is written.

Comment: yup, currently i do not have the code setup of grumpy and css of grumpy so unable to test it deeply, sorry :(

Comment: Thanks. I should note that yet more CSS would be needed to change the height than what we've discussed so far. For example, the menu icon for mobile screen size (it appears when one resizes the window to be smaller) would still be too large and not aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
// resize navbar height to 40px
.navbar {
    min-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
 }

.navbar ul li { 
  height: 40px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
  }

.navbar ul li > a { 
  height: 40px; 
  line-height: 38px; 
  }

// menu icon position when go to mobile mode
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
  .navbar a.toggle { 
    top: 0%;
  }
}
```

at least it works for me, good luck